# Does spark's collect() action, after an orderBy, provide the order preserved list?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sorting, collect

I have a dataframe in spark scala, when I perform a collect operation on the dataframe after an orderBy operation, will the order be preserved in the collected scala list?

```
val schema = StructType(Array(
                        StructField("language", StringType, true), 
                        StructField("users", IntegerType, true)))

val data = Seq(Row("Java", 20000), 
                 Row("Python", 100000), 
                 Row("Scala", 3000))

val df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema) 

//Performing an orderBy Operation. This will sort the data based on 
//the number of users in descending orders
val dfSorted = df.orderBy(col("users").desc)

//Now I collect the data, this is where I am not sure if the data will be sorted 
//or not, obviously because this ordering may happen on various executors 
//in the cluster.
val collectedDataList = dfSorted.collect()
```

I know that the order is preserved in the list in Scala but I am not sure if the collect operation will provide the ordered data.

Comment: Spark assures that the df is ordered as long you work with it in subsequent operations, but if the ordering process is executed using more than one partition, yes, the collect action can produce a scala collection with 'unordered' elements. If you, for whatever reason, need to collect the df taking in account this constraint just coalesce the df to one partition.